# IdentityServer4 - End Session in POST

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, .net-6.0

IdentityServer4 documentation explains how to use the end session endpoint using the HTTP method GET (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html).

Is it possible to configure it in order to accept POST requests as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/EndSessionEndpoint.cs), it seems that the endpoint accepts both GET and POST requests.

```
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(context.Request.Method))
        {
            parameters = context.Request.Query.AsNameValueCollection();
        }
        else if (HttpMethods.IsPost(context.Request.Method))
        {
            parameters = (await context.Request.ReadFormAsync()).AsNameValueCollection();
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Invalid HTTP method for end session endpoint.");
            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, altought the same request that works in GET doesn't work in POST. We are using a x-www-form-urlencoded body for the POST request and we are getting error code 405. The token we are sending is a valid Id Token. How is this possible?